# How to stick Admob banner to bottom of screen (swift)

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

I'm using a tableView, I would like to have an admob banner to be display in front of the tableView and to stick to the bottom of the screen (even when the user scroll down).

Answer (score 5):

You have to add as a tool bar. add this code in viewdidload

```
self.navigationController!.toolbarHidden = false
banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-YOurID"
banner.rootViewController = self
var request: GADRequest = GADRequest.request()
request.testDevices = [""]
banner.loadRequest(request)
self.navigationController.toolbar.addSubview(banner)
```

Comment: I deleted the .request from the line:  var request: GADRequest = GADRequest.request() , and it worked :D, Thanks

Comment: It's not a good solution. Banner Ads' height is 50px, but Toolbar's height is 44px. It is not OK for the design guidelines.

Comment: There're several options for the adSize, for iPhone X. You could try kGADAdSizeFluid and the size is almost perfect to me.